# Mostrar resultados de consulta sin repetir

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo lo siguiente y espero explicarlo lo mejor posible:

Tengo tres o cuatro tablas:

- estudiantes
- materias
- notas
- boletin

La tabla estudiantes tiene solo los datos personales:

```
(cod,nombres,direccion,email),
```

la tabla notas las calificaciones

```
(id, cod_est,cod_materia,nota),
```

la tabla materias

```
(cod,nombre,descripcion)
```

y por último boletín

```
(cod,cod_est,valor)
```

Lo que requiero hacer es lo siguiente: una cabecera por estudiante y sus detalles por ejemplo:

```
cabecera:Fred D.,identificación,número boletín 
detalle: matemáticas, descripción 
detalle: física,descripcion 
detalle: quimica,descripcion
cabecera:Jhonatan D.,identificación,número boletín
detalle:español,descripción
detalle:ingles,descripcion
cabecera:Slash K., 
identificación,número boletín
detalle:educación física
```

La consulta la hago bien, en una consulta realicé todo, pero al realizar el foreach, pues se me repite cabecera y detalle por registro encontrado, y así no lo necesito.

¿Se puede realizar como lo estoy preguntando, y si es así me pueden ayudar? No pegue código porque estoy desde el móvil.

Fracción de la consulta

```
<?php
$sqlDetalle = "SELECT estudiantes.cod,estudiantes.nombres,estudiantes.direccion,estudiantes.email,calificaciones.cod_est,calificaciones.cod_materia,calificaciones.nota,boletin.cod,calificaciones.nota
FROM estudiantes
RIGHT JOIN calificaciones ON estudiantes.cod = calificaciones.cod_est
RIGHT JOIN materias ON calificaciones.cod_materia = materias.cod AND materias.estado = 'A'
RIGHT JOIN boletin ON calificaciones.cod_est = boletin.cod_est 
WHERE estudiantes.cod IN ({$cod23}) AND estudiantes.estado = 'A'
ORDER BY calificaciones.cod_est ASC";
$detalle = $xhj->prepare($sqlDetalle);
$detalle -> execute();
$detalle = $detalle->fetchAll();
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: Buena sugerencia y gracias por editar la pregunta, ahora subo la parte de la consulta, ya lo puedo hacer

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo, más tarde la comparto. Gracias a todos